# "has lived in" or "has been living in"

Tags: verbs

Mr. ABC has lived in California since 2010, and he resides with his wife and two children.

Please let me know if "has lived in" in the above sentence is correct? Should it be " has been living in ...." since he still resides in California.

.......................

Since graduating from the University in 2009, Mr. ABC has resided in Las Vegas.

Same question as above.

*** Should it be " has been residing in ...." since he still resides in California.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another) and [Present perfect and perfect continuous for actions in progress](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68068/present-perfect-and-present-perfect-continuous-for-actions-in-progress), etc.

Comment: This question should be migrated to EL&U's sister site: [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) English Language Learners. I don't believe the duplicate questions answer the OP's query. He is asking if there is any difference between the present perfect and the present perfect continuous. None of the suggested questions deal with this aspect satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1):

According to me "has been living" is the right choice because Mr.ABC is still living in California . And we use "since" with the present perfect continuous if we talk about the grammar. 
If we use "has lived in" that means that he still lives in California but according to rules we do not add specific time with present perfect. 
And living and residing are both the same cases you can use either of them .

Comment: -1. This is wrong. "Since" and "for" are used with the present perfect tense, and the phrase "Mr. ABC **has lived** in California since 2010" means he is still living in California. The action is not completed but continues to the present day.

Comment: I forgot to add that the user can modify and edit his answer in order to improve its quality, in as far as he has only expressed an *opinion*. If he can prove his theory is correct, I will happily reverse my down-vote.